# The result of requests module is different between idle and code

Tags: python, python-requests

Why doesn't the wayback machine return an answer with this code?
What I tried: (1) python idle returned a normal answer.
(2) The status_code is 200 and the function returns None.

```
def wayback_search(url):
    res = requests.get("https://web.archive.org/cdx/search/cdx?url=%s&showDupeCount=true&output=json" % url,
                       headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    ### search in requests_module
    urllist = res.url.split('&')
    request_url = urllist[0][:-1] + '&' + urllist[1] + '&' + urllist[2]
    print('timestamps_url:', request_url)
    res = requests.get(request_url)
    
    if res.raise_for_status():
        cdx = res.json()
        print(res.url)
        print('cdx', cdx)

    res = requests.get("http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=%s" % url,
                       headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    if res.raise_for_status():
        cdx = res.json()
        print(res.url)
        print('cdx', cdx)
```

Perhaps the wayback isn't working at all.

Comment: what do you mean by "return an answer"? what are you expecting this code to do?

Answer (score 0):

I do not see where the function `wayback_search` is called. Also, there is no return statement in the function. In python, when no return statement is there in function, it returns `None`.. Try to return what you want

Also the code inside the `if res.raise_for_status()` should ideally never run because the `res.raise_for_status()` raises a exception.